# AVPlayer errors on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, avplayer

I am developing a mac app which is supposed to play a video from a url in a new window when a button is pressed. To create the AVPlayer, I have:

```
AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:url];
AVPlayerItem *playeritem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:urlAsset];
_vidPlayer.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playeritem];
```

where url is an http NSURL to an m4v video file, and _vidPlayer is an AVPlayerView. The video player appears, but the play button remains greyed out and I get a whole wall of log output I don't understand, see below. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
[22:12:42.904] FigAtomStreamInitWithByteStreamWithSize signalled err=-12893 (kFigAtomStream_OffsetOutsideOfParent) (Offset exceeds stream length) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia_frameworks/CoreMedia-1562.235/Sources/Utilities/FigAtomStream.c line 305
[22:12:42.967] FigLimitedDiskCacheProvider_CopyProperty signalled err=-12784 (kFigBaseObjectError_PropertyNotFound) (no such property) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.235/Prototypes/FigByteStreamPrototypes/FigLimitedDiskCacheProvider.c line 947
[22:12:43.146] itemasync_SetProperty signalled err=-12785 (kFigBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (invalidated) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.235/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c line 2293
[22:12:43.146] itemasync_SetProperty signalled err=-12785 (kFigBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (invalidated) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.235/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c line 2293
[22:12:43.146] itemasync_SetProperty signalled err=-12785 (kFigBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (invalidated) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.235/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c line 2293
[22:12:43.146] itemasync_SetProperty signalled err=-12785 (kFigBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (invalidated) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.235/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c line 2293
[22:12:43.146] itemasync_SetProperty signalled err=-12785 (kFigBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (invalidated) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.235/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c line 2293
[22:12:43.146] itemasync_CopyProperty signalled err=-12785 (kFigBaseObjectError_Invalidated) (invalidated) at /SourceCache/CoreMedia/CoreMedia-1562.235/Prototypes/Player/FigPlayer_Async.c line 2088
[22:12:43.146] (Fig) signalled err=-12871
<<< FFR_Movie >>> ParseTrackAtom: Omitting a track that encountered error -12871 during atom parsing
```

Thanks.

Comment: `AVPlayer` has no built in controls (only `MPMoviePlayerController` has), so I don't know what player you are using, but it's definitely not `AVPlayer`.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am using an AVPlayerView, not straight AVPlayer. AVPlayerView has built in controls (when you hover the mouse over, you get play/pause button, video progress bar, etc.)

Comment: I finally figured out an (albeit extremely janky) way of making this work, so I think I'm alright. Thanks to both of you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem coding in swift for iOS, and I've found this site very helpful: http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/swift-avfoundation/#audiofile

Not sure if you have the know how to convert swift to objective c (I sure don't, I'm a newb), but she may have some other articles on this site for you. Wish I could be more helpful, but hope this link leads to your answer.  Buenas suerta!